# How to pull <tspan> elements from HTML code in VBA webscraping

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to pull data from a webpage using HTML webscraping with VBA. I have been successful on other sites, but this one has the data within a line of code labeled tspan and I can't seem to get the data out of it.

The HTML code looks like this (sorry for long code, not sure what is and isn't relevant):

```
<div class="Classname">
    <svg width ="100%" height="100%" fill="code" stroke="100%" stroke="code" viewBox="numbers" class="undefined">
         <polygon fill="transparent" points="numbers"></polygon?
             <text y="100" dy="#s">
                <tspan x="100" text-anchor="middle">1</tspan>
```

The value I want is the 1 in the last line before . The code I am using to extract it after navigating to the correct webpage, etc, is:

```
Dim text As String
text=IE.document.GetElementsByClassname("Classname")(0).GetElementsByTagname("tspan")(0).innertext
```

I have also tried where the classname is "undefined" as it appears in the svg code line. I am getting error 91 either way.

Edit: I have now tried nested GetElementsByTagName, still getting error

```
text=IE.document.GetElementsByClassname("C")(0).GetElementsByTagname("svg")(0).GetElementsByTagname("polygon")(0).GetElementsByTagname("text")(0).GetElementsByTagname("tspan")(0).innertext
```

Comment: The most important question is if you are 100%, undoubtedly sure that the webpage is __completely loaded__ before you try to work with its elements?

Comment: I have a readystate complete loop built in that also has worked on other applications.

Comment: Can you provide the url?

Comment: https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/mmm/stock-analysis I am trying to pull the "smart score" rating, the large number in the upper left

Comment: Solved. The classname had an underscore, that was actually  2 underscores. __ vs _, hard to tell the difference. Nested getelementsbytagname did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more direct and quicker way

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.tipranks.com/stocks/mmm/stock-analysis"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Do 'could use timed loop here to handle infinite looping risk
            Set elem = .document.querySelectorAll("tspan")
        Loop While elem.Length = 0
        Debug.Print elem.item(0).innerText
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The classname had an underscore, that was actually  2 underscores. __ vs _, hard to tell the difference. Nested getelementsbytagname did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may also be able to use the querySelector method...

```
text = IE.document.querySelector("tspan[text-anchor='middle']").innerText
```

Hope this helps!